# Table of contents using Jekyll and Kramdown

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

I'm trying to use Kramdown's auto "Table of Contents" generator on a page (not a post) on my Jekyll site.

_includes/toc.html

```
<nav>
  <h4>Table of Contents</h4>
  {:toc}
</nav>
```

my_cool_stuff/my_cool_page.md

```
---
layout: page
---

{% include toc.html %}

# The title of my page
## The Subtitle of my page
```

The HTML is generated literally and I'm not getting a list of headers.

```
<nav>
  <h4 class="toc_title">On This Page</h4>
  {:toc}
</nav>
```

What am I setting up wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

{:toc} is [kramdown tag for automatic Table of content generation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc).

In your case, you need two more things to make it work :

1. Allow kramdown to parse inside html blocks : in `_config.yml` add :

   ```
   kramdown:
     parse_block_html: true
   ```
2. in `_includes/toc.html`, you need to provide a seed list :

   ```
   <nav>
     <h4>Table of Contents</h4>
     * this unordered seed list will be replaced by toc as unordered list
     {:toc}
   </nav>
   ```

Comment: I already follow this, but in my site, I still get the original html element in my site post. Any other reason I didn't know?

Comment: I’m using Jekyll and voted this up for the knowledge that you need an unordered list on the previous or next line for the table of contents to be rendered into.

Comment: Seems like kramdown only generates a toc for markdown headings. eg ```<h2>toptic</h2>``` won't be included.

Comment: It doesn't work in the layout. We have to put the code inside each post.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to do [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45931317/jekyll-kramdown-t-o-c-not-building) but was trying to avoid having any kind of markup in my post page, similar to your `{% include toc.html %}`.

I found this great Ruby Gem - [jekyll-toc](https://github.com/toshimaru/jekyll-toc) that allows you to place a TOC anywhere in a layout file. You enable it in the front matter.