# Kramdown table of content doesn't display inside HTML block

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

I was following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417624/table-of-contents-using-jekyll-and-kramdown), but it doesn't seem to take effect for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

_includes/layout.html

```
<main>
<div>
<!-- Sidebar -->
<aside markdown="1">
<h4>Table of Contents</h4>
* ToC
{:toc}
</aside>
<!-- END Sidebar -->

<!-- Main content -->
<article>
{{ content }}
</article>
<!-- END Main content -->
</div>
</main>
```

_config.yml

```
markdown: kramdown
```

Result:

[image]

## Update

_layouts/site.html

```
<aside markdown="1">
mark**down**
</aside>
```

It just renders as above. Kramdown is turned on in config.

Comment: It can be interesting to see all your code. Do you have a repository url ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I just generated sample site and put that markdown tag as an example. See this: https://tu5.github.io/jekyll-now/Hello-World/
Also: https://github.com/tu5/jekyll-now/blob/master/_layouts/post.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using [pure liquid ToC by allejo](http://allejo.io/blog/a-jekyll-toc-in-liquid-only).

```
% capture tocWorkspace %}
{% comment %}
    "...like all things liquid - where there's a will, and ~36 hours to spare, there's usually a/some way" ~jaybe

    Usage:
        {% include toc_pure_liquid.html html=content sanitize=true class="inline_toc" id="my_toc" h_min=2 h_max=3  %}

    Parameters:
        * html     (string) - the HTML of compiled markdown generated by kramdown in Jekyll

    Optional Parameters:
        * sanitize (bool)   : false  - when set to true, the headers will be stripped of any HTML in the TOC
        * class    (string) :   ''   - a CSS class assigned to the TOC
        * id       (string) :   ''   - an ID to assigned to the TOC
        * h_min    (int)    :   1    - the minimum TOC header level to use; any header lower than this value will be ignored
        * h_max    (int)    :   6    - the maximum TOC header level to use; any header greater than this value will be ignored

    Output:
        An unordered list representing the table of contents of a markdown block. This snippet will only generate the table of contents and will NOT output the markdown given to it
{% endcomment %}

{% capture my_toc %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign minHeader = include.h_min | default: 1 %}
{% assign maxHeader = include.h_max | default: 6 %}
{% assign nodes = include.html | split: '<h' %}
{% for node in nodes %}
    {% if node == "" %}
        {% continue %}
    {% endif %}
    {% assign headerLevel = node | replace: '"', '' | slice: 0, 1 %}
    {% assign headerLevel = headerLevel | times: 1 %}
    {% assign indentAmount = headerLevel | minus: minHeader | add: 1 %}
    {% assign _workspace = node | split: '</h' %}
    {% unless headerLevel >= minHeader %}
        {% continue %}
    {% endunless %}
    {% if headerLevel > maxHeader %}
        {% continue %}
    {% endif %}
    {% assign _idWorkspace = _workspace[0] | split: '"' %}
    {% assign html_id = _idWorkspace[1] %}
    {% capture _hAttrToStrip %}{{ headerLevel }} id="{{ html_id }}">{% endcapture %}
    {% assign header = _workspace[0] | replace: _hAttrToStrip, '' %}
    {% assign space = '' %}
    {% for i in (1..indentAmount) %}
        {% assign space = space | prepend: '  ' %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% capture my_toc %}{{ my_toc }}
{{ space }}- [{% if include.sanitize %}{{ header | strip_html }}{% else %}{{ header }}{% endif %}](#{{ html_id }}){% endcapture %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if include.class %}
        {% capture my_toc %}{:.{{ include.class }}}
{{ my_toc | lstrip }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if include.id %}
        {% capture my_toc %}{: #{{ include.id }}}
{{ my_toc | lstrip }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}
{% endcapture %}{% assign tocWorkspace = '' %}
{{ my_toc | markdownify }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory it should work that way, (it is not working for me either) but you can force to process the code inside a block with `markdown="1" like this:

```
<aside markdown="1">
<h4>Table of Contents</h4>
* ToC
{:toc}
</aside>
```

Make sure you don't indent the code inside the `aside` tag or it will be parsed as kramdown code.

> By default, kramdown parses all block HTML tags and all XML tags as
>   raw HTML blocks. However, this can be configured with the
>   parse_block_html. If this is set to true, then syntax parsing in HTML
>   blocks is globally enabled. It is also possible to enable/disable
>   syntax parsing on a tag per tag basis using the markdown attribute:
>
> If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="0", then the tag is parsed as raw HTML block.
>
> If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="1", then the default mechanism for parsing syntax in this tag is used.

## Update

I've checked your repo, you [need to](https://github.com/tu5/jekyll-now/pull/1) rename `index.html` to `index.md` so kramdown will parse it and then you can also add the line to `_config.yml` to parse markdown inside html blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I decided to simplify my question while you have written an answer. Anyway, it stays the same. Markdown still doesn't seem to work in my HTML block.

Comment: The answer remains the same also, it also works. You shouldn't completely change the original question, it is better to update the question so the other answers won't become useless.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will know for the future. Do you have maybe any other ideas why it still doesn't want to work?

Comment: I've made a pull request with changes and updated the answer, now is working ;)

Comment: I <3 you. Seems to work. Will play it after weekend. Thanks for saving my computer for being thrown from the window!

Comment: Happy to help, If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Not really solved, as I'm still having trouble with building it into my layout file. Turning HTML layout file into markdown breaks some things, and my question is - is there any other way to embed that ToC? Do you have an idea maybe?

Comment: You have several toc plugin generators, like [this one](https://github.com/toshimaru/jekyll-toc), but if you use github pages you will need to build the site before uploading it

Comment: Thanks @marcanuy
Your [pull request](https://github.com/tu5/jekyll-now/pull/1) really helped demonstrate how it could be done.

Comment: Also note that there is a difference between markdown="1" (enables for some elements - see link), markdown="block" (enables for block level elements) and markdown="span" (enables for span level elements). The global option parse_block_html enables parsing of the same elements as markdown="1". More about the options and what elements they enable parsing for here: https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll only parse `.md` or `.mardown` files.

`.html` files are not proccessed by markdown parser.

If you rename a file from `.html` to `.md`, it will be processed as kramdown.

But there you will have problems with indentation.

Mixing html and markdown is not so easy ;-)

Comment: I tried to include `{% include my.md %}` and put there the only markdown, but it didn't work too.

Comment: I think that including markdown in html file doesn't work.